# Multiple threads and Independent modal dialogs in Swing Frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, jtabbedpane

Consider a `JFrame` which has multiple tabs in a `JTabbedPane`. My target is to create threads/tasks within each tab and eventually handle modal dialogs independently for each tab.

For example, tab1 runs a task and requires an user input from a dialog, meanwhile tab2 also runs a task and requires another input in parallel.

Managing multiple tasks within multiple tabs via `SwingWorker` is fine but not sure how to display and manage modal dialogs. When user clicks on tab1, s/he should see dialog belongs to task in tab1; likewise in tab2. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's an interesting idea. Think about it this way. The interaction starts from the user, and the user can not interact in parallel.

In the case of a remote call or a log running job in background having a thread manage the network request or the Disk read/write (which could take some time) you create a new thread. So the main Application Thread remains responsive and can process user input.

Everytime a backgroudn thread completes. You show the result to the user.

So UI Main thread and new thread per long running task is all you need.

Comment: Looks like multiple modal popup not possible. Do you have idea how to implement a popup dialog in a tabbed pane? Dialogs will not be modal but each popup must be visible only in parent tab.